# New Error today on my yesterday running App. Unexpected Error

Tags: jetbrains-ide

it's an App I have been using since today. And in this morning I cannot use it anymore..
It gives me this error.
Last time I closed my computer was working and today no..  Any hints?

```
    at org.jetbrains.skiko.SkiaLayer.<init>(SkiaLayer.kt:37)
    at org.jetbrains.skiko.SkiaLayer.<init>(SkiaLayer.kt:24)
    at androidx.compose.desktop.ComposeLayer$Wrapped.<init>(ComposeLayer.desktop.kt:77)
    at androidx.compose.desktop.ComposeLayer.<init>(ComposeLayer.desktop.kt:57)
    at androidx.compose.desktop.ComposeWindow.<init>(ComposeWindow.desktop.kt:35)
    at androidx.compose.desktop.AppWindow.<init>(AppWindow.desktop.kt:116)
    at androidx.compose.desktop.AppWindow.<init>(AppWindow.desktop.kt)
    at androidx.compose.desktop.AppWindow_desktopKt$Window$1.run(AppWindow.desktop.kt:85)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:316)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:770)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:715)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:740)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
Caused by: org.jetbrains.skiko.LibraryLoadException: Cannot find skiko-windows-x64.dll.sha256, proper native dependency missing.
    at org.jetbrains.skiko.Library.load(Library.kt:43)
    at org.jetbrains.skiko.HardwareLayer.<clinit>(HardwareLayer.kt:10)
    ... 21 more
```

Comment: Exception shows that the required native library (`skiko-windows-x64.dll.sha256`) is missing. I'd suggest submitting  ticket to https://github.com/JetBrains/skiko/issues

Comment: Hi, have you found a solution?

Comment: No, it only works for me this:

I did uninstall the Intellij. It gives the option to delete cache and delete configurations. I did it. After, just download and install again the program. It works fine now. If anyone have another solution...

Answer (score -1):

I did uninstall the Intellij. It gives the option to delete cache and delete configurations. I did it. After, just download and install again the program.
It works fine now!

Comment: Do you have any alternative? for me is the only way I could do it... Tell mee..